# How to populate the pull down menu?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to populate the pull down menu. so far ive got:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>NZ Currency Converter</TITLE>
 </HEAD>
<BODY>
<p><tr>
<td colspan="2" align="right">&nbsp;&nbsp;The other currency is:</td>
<td>
  <select name="the other currency is:">
    <% List<Currency.Models.exchrate> exchrateList = (List <Currency.Models.exchrate>) ViewData["exchrateList"];
       foreach (Currency.Models.exchrate st in exchrateList)
       {
    %>  
       <option value="<% Response.Write(st.othercurrency);%>">"<% Response.Write(st.fromnzd);%>">"
<% Response.Write (st.tonzd);%>">
</option> 
    <% } %>
    <option value=""></option>
  </select>
     </td>
</tr>


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Currency.Models;

namespace Currency.Controllers
{
[HandleError]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        financeInit();
        return View();
    }

    public void financeInit()
    {

        financeEntities db = new financeEntities();
        ViewData["exchrate"] = db.exchrates.ToList();
        ViewData["Convert From NZD"] = "";
        ViewData["Convert To NZD"] = "";
        ViewData["You wish to convert"] = "";
        ViewData["That will produce"] = "";


    }
    public ActionResult financeCurrencyConvert()
    {
        return View();
    }
         }
    }
```

This is my home controller view currently which is linked to the database from which the pull down menu will be populated. what more can i add to this. i am new to asp.net and not sure how web development works so any help will be appreciated. In the pulldown menu instead of countries im getting their conversion rates. can anyone help with how to change this to select as countries

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: object refence not set to an instance of an object.Exchrate is highlighted

Comment: I can't see you setting `ViewData["exchrateList"]` in your code behind. Maybe `ViewData["The Other Currency is:"] = db.exchrates.ToList();` should be `ViewData["exchrateList"] = db.exchrates.ToList();` ?

Comment: thank you. its kind of working now. still need to add a bit of work to it for the pull down to show accurate info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are using different view data keysin controller and view (`"The Other Currency is:"` in controller and `"exchrateList"` in view). Match them and you should be ok - for example, change this line from controller

```
ViewData["The Other Currency is:"] = db.exchrates.ToList();
```

to

```
ViewData["exchrateList"] = db.exchrates.ToList();
```

Comment: thank you. its kind of working now. still need to add a bit of work to it for the pull down to show accurate info.

Comment: In the pulldown menu im getting numbers instead of words such as America, china etc. Do you know what the reason for this might be

Comment: @gauri, that will be the issue in the option mark-up that you have emitted - correct syntax would be something like `<option value="10.23">USD</option>`. Perhaps, you should try `<option value='<%=st.fromnzd%>'><%= st.othercurrency ></option>`